# changing the values in an array using foreach Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am working on foreach in javascript, and I am wondering how to replace its old value to the new value in an array.

Let say I have this array

```
var myArray = [];
```

and then I have this variables to store the value

```
var name = [{name: "Peter"}, {name:"Jimmy"}, {name: Bob}];
var country = [{country: "Canada"}, {country:"Mexico"}, {country: "United States"}];
```

After I push the array, and display it to the views, I should have something like this in the table:

```
Name:    Country:
Peter     Canada
Jimmy     Mexico
Bob       United States
```

Then I also have the edit button so that I can edit the content in the table

```
Name:    Country:
Peter     Canada
Jimmy     Mexico
Bob       United States
<button ng-click="editDetail()">Edit Button </button>
```

What I want to do is, I want to change to be able to replace the old content to new content in the table and save it back to the array.

```
Name:    Country:
Amy       Britian
Jimmy     Spain
Ken       United States
```

How can I use foreach methods to do it? I am not sure what to do in this foreach function. Help will be appreciated :)

```
myArray.foreach(function(){


})
```

Comment: Why not start with saving just one piece of data? Then you just `foreach (pieceofdata) mysavefunction` (pseudo code)

Comment: Ya, why at the beginning don't you have just one array of objects containing all the relevant datas? `var datas = [{name: "Peter", country: "Canada"}, {name:"Jimmy", country: "Spain"}];`

Comment: @Jan, do you mean start with let say change Canada to Britain First, and than foreach (country) ?

Comment: @A.Wolff, I guess you can do it this way, but isn't it just the same?

Comment: I mean, start out creating the logic to change one piece of data (f.e. Canada to Britain). Then when you have that logic in place you can just loop through that logic for all your data.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is not use `forEach`, but use `map`, which essentially is the same, but you'll return a new array with your new data replacing the old data.

See the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var myNewArray = myArray.map(function(d) {
   return d;
});
```